# Counting results of join on duplicate field

Tags: mysql, join, count, distinct

I have a table1 containing duplicate column value

Table1

```
id   code
1   201202  0000    1111
2   201202  0000    9999
3   201203  0000    9999
4   201203  0000    0999
5   201204  1000    1999
6   201204  2000    2999
7   201205  3000    3999
8   201205  4000    4999
9   201205  5000    5999
```

Table 2

```
id   numbers
1   2012020010  
2   2012024929  
3   2012033838
4   2012052434
5   2012052229
6   2012052232
```

I want to count all the numbers in table2 that are substring of distinct code in table 1
i.e. result should be

```
code   frequency
201202   2
201203   1
201205   3
```

I have been able to get all the numbers for every code but can't figure out how to count them

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.code , table1.id, table2.number AS ph_npa, count( * )
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON substr( table2.number, 1, 6 ) = table1.code
GROUP BY table1.number
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I got it working and query is super fast

SELECT

DISTINCT A.code as code, 
B.Counts AS frequency
FROM table1 AS A

INNER JOIN (

SELECT substr( number, 1, 6 ) AS subnumber, count( 1 ) AS Counts
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY substr( number, 1, 6 )
) 
AS B ON A.code = B.subnumber

i.e.
select the number and frequency of number from table 2
and then join with distinct code form table 1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really one for using the "inner join" syntax and prefer to just use the cleaner looking implicit join on the data.

```
select
  count(*)
from
  npanxxsmall n, phone_numbers p
where
  substr(n.code, 1, 6) = substr(p.number, 1, 6);
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: the result is same as the solution of robin above, result returned is the frequency of code in table1

Comment: You're right, I've amended it to just give the count and not the frequency.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.code, COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM table_one AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_two AS t2
ON t2.numbers LIKE CONCAT(t1.code, '%')
GROUP BY t1.code
```

Either use `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` depending on if you want rows with `frequency = 0` or not. All I did was basicly to run a `LIKE` as join condition with the `%` wildcard.

Comment: actually the result returned is the frequency of code in table1 but I want is the frequency of numbers that are substr(1,6) of code in table1

Comment: correction: frequency of numbers that are substr(1,6) of code in **table2**

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following. It can have performance hits on large data sets, but will get you started. It is working with my test data.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(t2.numbers, 1,6) AS CODE, COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM table_2 t2
WHERE SUBSTR(t2.numbers, 1,6) IN (SELECT t1.code FROM table_1 t1)
GROUP BY SUBSTR(t2.numbers, 1,6)
```

Let me know if its working!